# Applet - align text to bottom middle

Tags: java, applet, awt, text-alignment

Is there a way to align text from `g.drawString()` to the bottom center of a java applet?

I am also hoping for a way that is fluid between full-screen and small screen.

Comment: *"I am also hoping for a way that is fluid between full-screen and small screen."*  Hopes are perhaps best fulfilled by asking *one* specific question at a time. ;) BTW Tip: If there is a to need to add the major tag in the title, it needs to be more specific.  Glad you got it sort.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, start by taking a look at [Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

```
String text = "Happy at the bottom";
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
int y = (getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent();
g.drawString(text, x, y);
```

The next question that needs to asked, is could what you want be achieved by using a `JLabel` and a `BorderLayout` (or other compound layout)....?

Comment: MadProgrammer-you keep answering my questions! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of some help (for a change ;))